# How to check whether an android device supports DLNA or not programmatically

Tags: android, dlna

I want to check whether an android device supports DLNA or not programmatically,Is there a way to find it,i did try in the developers website but i couldn't find it,

Comment: What do you mean by "...supports DLNA or not..."? Just to qualify my question, I do know what DLNA is, I just don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Android device supports DLNA.coz I am working on it:)

Comment: can you suggest me from which version and any APi's related to it,i have a requirement to check whether the device supports DLNA to display the menu accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cling to write UPnP/DLNA Android clients or even server applications.

All features of  Cling Core are supported on Android
    The full source code of the UPnPBrowser example application of the manual can be found [here](http://4thline.org/projects/download/misc/).

Comment: Thanks Raghu for your answer which gave some idea of how DLNA works,Thank you very much